# Showing that mappings $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ are linear transformations and finding their matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Problem:** Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$ by identifying $\binom{a}{b}$ to $z=a+ib$. Show that the following mappings $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ are linear transformations, and give their matrices.

- $\mathrm{Re}\colon z\mapsto \mathrm{Re}(z)$ (the real part of $z$);
- $\mathrm{Im}\colon z\mapsto \mathrm{Im}(z)$ (the imaginary part of $z$);
- $c\colon z\mapsto\overline{z}$ (the complex conjugate of $z$);
- $m_w\colon w\mapsto wz$, where $w=u+iv$ is a fixed complex number.

**My work:** I showed that these are all linear transformations, but I just wanted to double check on the matrices I came up with, in order:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For example, we know that $wz=(ua-vb)+i(ub+av)$ and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}ua-vb\\av+ub\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Do the matrices I came up with look correct based on these kinds of observations?

Comment: Your work is correct

Comment: @anon But $w$ is *defined* to be $w=u+iv$. If $m_w$ is a linear transformation $\mathbf{x}\mapsto A\mathbf{x}$, then $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$, no?

Comment: Oops, I read wrong.

Comment: @anon Interesting--that's what I originally had but changed it because what goes *in* is $w=\binom{u}{v}$...so would the matrix $A$ be as you suggested and what goes in is $\binom{a}{b}$? If so, how is that?

Comment: I think it's a typo, $z$ should be going in, cause it is clearly said $w$ is a given constant

Comment: @dEmigOd Oh wow (you're totally right). Checked the author's errata and saw nothing for this problem. Thought well yeah it's just gotta be a typo. Turns out I copied the damn thing down wrong (I looked back at my book explicitly). Okay well good...guess I understand this stuff then because it all is very clear now. Good spot and thanks for clearing up the confusion.